# Was Starkiller base ever tested?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

If I remember correctly the Death Star was "tested" on Alderaan. But it seems to me that Starkiller's first time use was against the new republic.

Is this the case? Or had Starkiller been tested previously?

Comment: What's wrong with testing against the republic?  Seems like a great way to test it to me!

Comment: @CHEESE Me too, I was just wondering if they had tested it previously, I mean they effectively wipe themselves out if the planet blows up. Although not completely as Kylo Ren is on his ship...

Comment: Yea it also seems like a pretty expensive test to me.

Comment: It would have been funny if it had malfunctioned and exploded

Comment: @CHEESE Unless it turns out it doesn't work, and they just alerted the Republic to the existence of YET ANOTHER Death Star, and the attempt to use it against them, igniting the war with the Republic that they were trying to avoid. There's a reason the US tested their first a-bomb in New Mexico, not Hiroshima.

Comment: Tarkin didn't call the use of the Death Star on Alderaan a "test". He called it a "demonstration". It wasn't the test of the Death Star, it was just the first time it was used _publicly_.

Comment: @Plutor Exactly. The first time it was used we will (most likely) see in the upcoming Rogue One.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Was the Death Star ever tested?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146893/was-the-death-star-ever-tested)

Comment: @Ward The two objects are mutually exclusive, the Death Star IS NOT Starkiller Base, will people stop trying to close this as a dupe of that

Comment: The Death Star was tested on Jedha and Scariff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by the content of General Hux's speech, it seems to me like he's implying that it's the first time:

> This fierce machine which you have built, upon which we stand…

Also, he's turned it into a pep talk event; it wouldn't have as much punch if it were the second time the weapon had been fired.

Also, how do you fire it (in any direction) without giving yourself away?

**Edit:**

I know this is a little late, but I just realized that the movie itself contains some pretty clear evidence that this is indeed the first time that the Starkiller has been fired at full power.  It's the scene in which a swath of forest gets razed by the force of the blast.

[image]

These are apparently large, mature trees that take decades to grow, definitely much longer than the time it took to build the weapon and maybe even before the First Order was created. If the Starkiller had recently fired, then this scene would be a desolate moonscape, not a real live forest.

Note, however, that this scene does not disprove the possibility that the weapon has been fired before at lower power levels.  We don't know what other sections of the forest, such as those closer to the power, look like.

Comment: This is probably the best info we have at the moment, although not much to go on, so I will accept it